# Is it possible to use slash commands in dms for discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]I don't know how but I had got this working long ago, but I don't have the code anymore and I'm not even use if it was slash command or regular command.

As you can see this was me using the bot in my dms. Now I have a new bot and I'm trying to do this by adding the guild id of my personal account but it gives me this error

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

This is how my slash commands look like:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)


@slash.slash(name="test", guild_ids=[guild_id_of_server])
async def test(ctx: SlashContext):
    ...
```

And this works flawlessly in my server, I just want it to make it work in my dms. Should change the permissions of the bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added `guild_ids=[guild_id_of_server]` so it will **only work on server**

```
@slash.slash(name="test", guild_ids=[guild_id_of_server])
async def test(ctx: SlashContext):
```

Just remove it and done!

```
@slash.slash(name="test")
async def test(ctx: SlashContext):
```