# How to make a Discord slash command usuable in DMs

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I want to use a slash command in DMs. Take this simple test.py file in the folder cogs/.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

  @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Loaded test command cog.")

  @app_commands.command(name="test", description="Test command")
  async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Hello')

async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Outside the cogs folder is my launch_bot.py file which start the bot:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

with open("cogs/jsons/settings.json") as json_file:
    data_dict = json.load(json_file)
    guild_id = data_dict["guild_id"]

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix = "kt$", 
            intents = discord.Intents.all(),
            tree_cls=CustomCommandTree)
        
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                await self.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
        
    async def on_ready(self):
        application_info = await self.application_info()
        bot_owner = application_info.owner
        await bot_owner.create_dm()
        self.bot_owner_dm_channel = bot_owner.dm_channel
        
        await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(presence_message))
        
        print(f"Logged in as\n\tName: {self.user.name}\n\tID: {self.user.id}")
        print(f"Running pycord version: {discord.__version__}")
        print(f"Synced commands to guild with id {guild_id}.")

bot = MyBot()
bot.run(bot_token)
```

I tried following the instructions which were described in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806440/is-it-possible-to-use-slash-commands-in-dms-for-discord-py) but I have no guild specified, so this doesn't work.
The [docs](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/ext/commands/slash_commands.html#getting-started) says it should work but it doesn't for me any ideas?

Comment: This code doesn't look like Pycord, it looks like discord.py 2.0. As well, the docs you linked are for disnake, which is completely separate from those two libraries. The SO post you've linked is for discord_slash, which is an outdated plugin library for discord.py 1.7.3 and is completely different from discord.py 2.0. I would recommend ensuring you're following the right guides/documentation when coding in discord.py, it can get confusing at times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **pycord**, at least for me commands were **usable in dm's by default.** I'll show you how to disable that if you ever need to.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def example(ctx):
#do things
```